# How to speed up QPainter drawpoint();?

Tags: performance, qt, draw, qpainter, paintevent

I want to draw many points by drawPoint().

It's possible, but too slow when call repaint() or update().

Normally I'm draw more than 1,000,000 points.

What shoud I do?

Comment: There should be no need to draw more points than there are pixels on a screen. If you explain what you're doing and show us the code you have, then we'll be able to give you an idea of how to optimise it.

Answer (score 0):

Option I see in a first glance is to draw everything you need into QPixmap as an intermediate cache and update it only then your data has being changed, while using it for redraw then needed.